# CSS/tables: how to put two versions of a text side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, tabular

I'm trying to create a page that has the Czech translation of a text running in parallel with the original English text. I've got the two texts in a nearly finished state. But I'm really not sure how to put them side by side, so that they run in parallel. (I think it would be too much to insist that each *paragraph* begin at the same horizontal location in both languages, but I do think it's a good idea to do it for each of the thirteen *sections*.)

[Here](http://www.dinkypage.com/124733) is the Czech text

[Here](http://www.dinkypage.com/137154) is the English text

I've received some suggestions about using tables, but I have no idea how that might work. I'd definitely appreciate any help.

Comment: You could put each section in a `div` and then each section's part in a `div` each and then `float: left` and `width: 50%` on both.

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/BzpeC/

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried about whether this would accommodate the paragraph and page numbers. What do you think?

Comment: I copy and pasted something wrong, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BzpeC/1/

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit of a different problem there that's quite a bit more complex if the English and Czech page numbers aren't meant to line up.

Comment: Right, because they have different pagination. I mainly just want to put them side-by-side.

Comment: Then that fiddle should show you how to do it (or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BzpeC/2/) with a simple page DIV included). I imagine you might have to rethink your markup approach somewhat, but it shouldn't be that much of a problem. I'd try something first, and if you can't get it worked out, ask THAT question.

Comment: Well, it's doing pretty poorly (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BzpeC/4/)). The Czech paragraph numbers are misbehaving and each new section brings weird disaster. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree a table is probably the best way to go.  Here's the simple code to put them in 2 columns.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>English Version</td>
    <td>Czech</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You will want to make sure your columns get bigger / smaller based on screen size.  You can either do this by setting the columns  with a width of X percent or X pixels.  Pixels will make them static width percent will give you dynamic width.